# How do you make sure the query portion of a request/response body is x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth

I'm using Gravity Forms REST API v2 which allows for some queries to be added to the base URL.  I have no problems creating a valid OAuth1 signature when I don't need to add a query to a URL, but I'm running into problems with the `oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849.signature.collect_parameters()` function when I add a query to the base URL.  How do I properly encode queries that need to be added to the URL?

My code works if `uri_query = ""`, but I need to figure out how to add a query to the URL for this to be useful.

```
import oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849.signature as oauth

pageNum = 1
pageSize = 10
uri_query = f'_labels=1&paging[current_page]={pageNum}&paging[page_size]={pageSize}'

data = []

headers = {
    "Authorization": (
        f'OAuth realm="", '
        f'oauth_nonce={nonce}, '
        f'oauth_timestamp={timestamp}, '
        f'oauth_consumer_key={consumerKey}, '
        f'oauth_signature_method={signatureMethod}, '
        f'oauth_version={version}')}

params = oauth.collect_parameters(uri_query=uri_query,
                                  body=data,
                                  headers=headers,
                                  exclude_oauth_signature=True,
                                  with_realm=False)
```

I expect `params` to be created without an error, but I get the following error.

```
Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters: {']', '['} in the string: '_labels=1&paging[current_page]=1&paging[page_size]=20'. Please ensure the request/response body is x-www-form-urlencoded.: ValueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 115, in lambda_handler
d = send_request(baseUrl, httpMethod, query, consumerKey)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 68, in send_request
signature = create_signature(baseUrl, httpMethod, query, nonce, timestamp, consumerKey, signatureMethod, version)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 52, in create_signature
with_realm=False)
File "/opt/python/oauthlib/oauth1/rfc5849/signature.py", line 270, in collect_parameters
params.extend(urldecode(uri_query))
File "/opt/python/oauthlib/common.py", line 134, in urldecode
raise ValueError(error % (set(query) - urlencoded, query))
ValueError: Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters: {']', '['} in the string: '_labels=1&paging[current_page]=1&paging[page_size]=20'. Please ensure the request/response body is x-www-form-urlencoded.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a URL encoded dictionary using `urllib.parse` methods (`urlencode(dict(parse_qsl(uri_query))`).  Final code should look something like this...

```
import oauthlib.oauth1.rfc5849.signature as oauth
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl, urlencode

pageNum = 1
pageSize = 10
uri_query = f'_labels=1&paging[current_page]={pageNum}&paging[page_size]={pageSize}'

data = []

headers = {
    "Authorization": (
        f'OAuth realm="", '
        f'oauth_nonce={nonce}, '
        f'oauth_timestamp={timestamp}, '
        f'oauth_consumer_key={consumerKey}, '
        f'oauth_signature_method={signatureMethod}, '
        f'oauth_version={version}')}

params = oauth.collect_parameters(uri_query=urlencode(dict(parse_qsl(uri_query)),
                                  body=data,
                                  headers=headers,
                                  exclude_oauth_signature=True,
                                  with_realm=False)
```